# bash: svnserve: command not found

Tags: hosting, svn, scm

I'm attempting to setup an svn server. It's working on the server fine but when I attempt to access it externally via

`svn list --verbose svn+ssh://name@domain.com/home/user/repo/svn/project`

I get the following error...

`bash: svnserve: command not found`

I did some searching and some people suggest it's a `.bashrc` issue but I've set the path like so already.. `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` where `svnserve` is located in /bin in my home dir.
Anyone know how to fix this?

edit // These commands tell me...

```
me@domain.com [~]# echo $PATH 
 /ramdisk/bin:/usr/sec/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/ramdisk/bin:/usr/sec/bin:/usr/lib64/qt- 3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home2/me/bin:/home2/me/bin:/home2/me/system/bin

me@domain.com [~]# ls -l 
$HOME/bin/svnserve -rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 165321 Jul 26 17:18 /home2/me/bin/svnserve* –`
```

edit 2//
doing `\ls -lb $HOME/bin/svnserve` gives me..

```
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 165321 Jul 26 17:18 /home2/me/bin/svnserve
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean access it externally? are you running svn list from another machine on the network? Have you already started svnserve daemon on the server using svnserve -d <repo directory>??

Comment: bash: svnserve: command not found  This is weird, why would svnserve be run when accessing the repo from a different machine? More details please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you haven't restarted your session in order to make the new `PATH` active (or do `source ~/.bashrc`) or `svnserve` hasn't been marked as executable (`chmod +x $HOME/bin/svnserve`) or the permissions are wrong.

What do these commands tell you?

```
echo $PATH    # Does this include $HOME/bin?
ls -l $HOME/bin/svnserve    # Is it present? What are the permissions and ownership?
```

Comment: @Aidan: I can't really read that. It would be better to edit your question and add it there where it can be formatted. (Also, you can shorten your prompt to "$" or "#" to make things easier to read.) I'm assuming that asterisk at the end of the filename is because you have `ls` aliased to include `-F`. If you do `\ls -lb $HOME/bin/svnserve` (including the backslash at the beginning) is the asterisk still there?

Comment: updated the question as per your request